# How to add labels on axis in ternary diagram using ggtern package?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, data-analysis, ggtern

The ternary diagram is shown in the following image. I want to add the labels of Z=60, Z=90 and Y=60 using ggtern package in R.

The R code link is [the R code of ternary diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44795107/how-to-fill-colors-correctly-using-geom-polygon-in-ggtern)

[image: ternary diagram]

Comment: I have added a new geometry in the latest version to make this type of thing a little easier, check out: geom_text_viewport and geom_label_viewport, http://www.ggtern.com/2017/07/23/version-2-2-1-released/. You will still need to suppress the mask, or place it below the text layers, but those two geometries are more intuitive for placing labels relative to the x and y cartesian [0,1] limits of the viewport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the perfect answer, but I tried to achieve your wanted result with `annotate` like this:

```
ggtern(data=DATA,aes(x,y,z)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=Series),alpha=.5,color="black",size=0.25) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=as.character(unique(DATA$Series))) +
  theme(legend.position=c(0,1),legend.justification=c(0,1)) + 
  labs(fill="Region",title="Sample Filled Regions") +
  annotate(geom  = 'text',
           x     = c(0.1, 1/3, 0.0),
           y     = c(0.0, 0.0, 1.5),
           z     = c(0.5, 1/3, 1.0),
           angle = c(0, 0, 0),
           vjust = c(2.5, 2.5, -1.5),
           hjust = c(0.0, -0.2, 0.0),
           label = c("Z=90","Z=60","Y=60"),
           color = c("black","gray",'orange')) + # for inspection
  theme_nomask()   # allows drawing beyond the borders
```

This yields the following picture:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A rather "raw" solution is to work with grobs.
After finding the text grobs containing the x, y, and z labels (initially placed at the vertex of the triangle), we move each label in the required position.

```
library(ggtern)
library(grid)
g <- data.frame(y=c(1,0,0),
                x=c(0,1,.4),
                z=c(0,0,.6),         Series="Green")
p <- data.frame(y=c(1,0.475,0.6),
                x=c(0,0.210,0),
                z=c(0,0.315,.4),         Series="Red")
q <- data.frame(y=c(0.575,0.475,0.0,0.0),
                x=c(0.040,0.210,0.4,0.1),
                z=c(0.385,0.315,0.6,0.9),         Series="Yellow")
f <- data.frame(y=c(0.6,0.575,0.0,0.0),
                x=c(0.0,0.040,0.1,0.0),
                z=c(0.4,0.385,0.9,1.0),         Series="Blue")
DATA = rbind(g, p, q, f)

p <- ggtern(data=DATA,aes(x,y,z)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=Series),alpha=.5,color="black",size=0.25) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=as.character(unique(DATA$Series))) +
  theme(legend.position=c(0,1),legend.justification=c(0,1)) + 
  labs(fill="Region",title="Sample Filled Regions")+
  xlab("X=60")+ylab("Y=60")+zlab("Z=90")

gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
grobPanel <- gt$grobs[[which(gt$layout$name == "panel")]] 
grobLabels <- grobPanel$children[[length(grobPanel$children)]]

# X-axes label
gt$grobs[[which(gt$layout$name == "panel")]]$children[[length(grobPanel$children)]]$children[[2]]$x <- unit(0.6,"npc")
gt$grobs[[which(gt$layout$name == "panel")]]$children[[length(grobPanel$children)]]$children[[2]]$y <- unit(0.1,"npc")
gt$grobs[[which(gt$layout$name == "panel")]]$children[[length(grobPanel$children)]]$children[[2]]$gp$fontsize <- 14

# Y-axes label
gt$grobs[[which(gt$layout$name == "panel")]]$children[[length(grobPanel$children)]]$children[[1]]$x <- unit(0.7,"npc")
gt$grobs[[which(gt$layout$name == "panel")]]$children[[length(grobPanel$children)]]$children[[1]]$y <- unit(0.6,"npc")
gt$grobs[[which(gt$layout$name == "panel")]]$children[[length(grobPanel$children)]]$children[[1]]$gp$fontsize <- 14

# Z-axes label
gt$grobs[[which(gt$layout$name == "panel")]]$children[[length(grobPanel$children)]]$children[[3]]$x <- unit(0.75,"npc")
gt$grobs[[which(gt$layout$name == "panel")]]$children[[length(grobPanel$children)]]$children[[3]]$y <- unit(0.1,"npc")
gt$grobs[[which(gt$layout$name == "panel")]]$children[[length(grobPanel$children)]]$children[[3]]$gp$fontsize <- 14

grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]